# How to reference specific cell location for conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to make the conditional formatting to reference each cell location that is visible. (It has been filtered)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P24").AutoFilter Field:=3, Critical:="Tuesday"
LR=Range("B" & RowsCount).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1:P" &LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

The formula for the conditional formatting is

```
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:= xlExpression, Formula1:=_
"INDEX(SHEET2!$2:$2, MATCH(B2,SHEET2!$2:$2,0)=4"
```

How do I make B2 = every visible cell that is selected?
For example, if I go to D5, it should say

```
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:= xlExpression, Formula1:=_
"INDEX(SHEET2!$2:$2, MATCH(D5,SHEET2!$2:$2,0)=4"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first selected cell **in your range** is cell "A1" in your formatting formula. If you do not set `$` inside the references, these references will be adjusted in the same manner as when using e.g. "fill down" (copying formulas from one place to another).

Afterwards, you may set the range of cells that this formula applies to. This is not possible *in the formula*.

*Hmm... I realize I haven't played around with this enough to be entirely sure, always selecting upper left cell first and pulling out from there. Then using A1 in the conditional formula.*